# why my returned value from recursive function is giong wrong

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, return-value

My function gets an array of chars, size, current place, and counter.
I need it **to print all the possible combination of A,B,C** (no AA and no CCC) in the length of the sized entered.
When size is above 3 the value of the function is returning a non-reasonable value that I didn't find the reason for it.

```
int abc(char arr[],int lastPlace,int curPlace,int count){
    if (curPlace == lastPlace){
        arr[curPlace] = '\0';
        printf("%s, ", arr);
        return 1;    
    }
    if(!curPlace || arr[curPlace - 1] != 'A'){
        arr[curPlace] = 'A';
        count += abc(arr, lastPlace, curPlace + 1, 0);
    }
    arr[curPlace] = 'B';
    count += abc(arr, lastPlace, curPlace + 1, 0);
    if(curPlace < 2 || arr[curPlace - 1] != 'C' || arr[curPlace - 2] != 'C'){
        arr[curPlace] = 'C';
        count+=abc(arr, lastPlace, curPlace + 1, 0);
        if (curPlace == 0)
            return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting warnings that not all cotrol paths return a value?

Comment: if you only have `A`, `B` and `C` (and don't want to repeat them), how can expect combinations above size 3?

Comment: Please provide with which arguments `abc` is called, and what the output should look like. I can compile it, but have no idea what you really want.

Comment: i do get the warning, but thak to this mark i fixed it and i deleted the if term in the end and mooved the return out of the block.

Comment: @asifevgy Please make an answer with the correct code then.

Answer (score -1):

```
int abc(char arr[], int lastPlace, int curPlace, int count) 
{
    if (curPlace == lastPlace)
    {
        arr[curPlace] = '\0';
        printf("%s, ", arr);
        return 1;
    }
    if(!curPlace || arr[curPlace-1]!='A'){
        arr[curPlace] = 'A';
        count += abc(arr, lastPlace, curPlace + 1, 0);
    }

    arr[curPlace] = 'B';
    count += abc(arr, lastPlace, curPlace + 1, 0);

    if(curPlace < 2 || arr[curPlace - 1] != 'C' || arr[curPlace - 2] != 'C')
    {
        arr[curPlace] = 'C';
        count += abc(arr, lastPlace, curPlace + 1, 0);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: some kind of explanation would be great